# Can I get numpy array from a tensorflow 2.0 dataset?

Tags: tensorflow

Can I get a `numpy` array from a `tensorflow dataset`? In the example below I can iterate over and get a `numpy array` from each `tensor`. But can I get it directly from `dataset`?

```
>>> X = tf.reshape(tf.range(2*3), (2, 3))
<tf.Tensor: id=33, shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]], dtype=int32)>

>>> dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
<TensorSliceDataset shapes: (3,), types: tf.int32>

>>> t = next(iter(dataset))
<tf.Tensor: id=40, shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)> 

>>> t.numpy()
array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: You can only iterate over the `tf.data.Dataset` to get its values. That's the only method.

Comment: `next(iter(dataset.batch(2))).numpy()`

Comment: Even simpler: `[i.numpy() for i in dataset]`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (see [here](https://www.kaggle.com/mgornergoogle/five-flowers-with-keras-and-xception-on-tpu)):

```
def dataset_to_numpy_util(dataset, N):
    dataset = dataset.unbatch().batch(N)
    for images, labels in dataset:
        numpy_images = images.numpy()
        numpy_labels = labels.numpy()
        break;  
    return numpy_images, numpy_labels
```